# CKEditor5 Custom Build Image Issue

Tags: ckeditor5

Getting this image html format when using getData() in CKEditor five with custom build:

```
![](/api/v1/config/template/temp/file/14fcd6-577c-586f-242-0632fb50fc5/6514462c-83d1-4fad-9239-cea69ac19097.png)
```

Would expect getting something like:

```
<figure><image url="/api/v1/config/template/temp/file/14fcd6-577c-586f-242-0632fb50fc5/6514462c-83d1-4fad-9239-cea69ac19097.png"/><figure>
```

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by removing Markdown plugin in my custom build.
Got the idea here: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/8787